# Python login a web by requests module

Tags: python, web, python-requests

I am trying to log into a website by requests module. The blank to be filled as username has no "name" attribute, nor does the password. However, that is what request need to konw. So what should I do to log in? 
The website is: 
https://passport.lagou.com/login/login.html

Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Open your favorite browser's Developer Tools (F12 on Chrome, Ctrl+Shift+I on Firefox, etc.), and reproduce the HTTP request displayed in the Network tab when trying to login.

In your case, some parameters like `username` and `password` are being sent as Form Data in a POST request to https://passport.lagou.com/login/login.json

Depending on the web application's implementation, you might also need to send some request headers, and it could also simply not work at all for various reasons.

Comment: Thank you, Anthony.  After knowing that username and password are being sent to https://passport.lagou.com/login/login.json. 
What should the login data format be? Which attribute should I choice?  In a regular form, we set as follows:
login_data = {'username': '#####', 'password': '#####'}
What should I set this time?  Thank you.

Comment: No, they are sent as Form Data with a "application/x-www-form-urlencoded" MIME type, and they encode the password on the client side, so you can't send the clear password either. Please check the sent request in a browser's Developer Tools: you need to reverse-engineer what they are doing if you want have a chance to get in. Good luck :)

Comment: Thank you so much!